# Laravel server push

Tags: javascript, laravel, events, server

I cannot figure why I cannot implement this in Laravel 5.3
To test I just did pure php and javascript:

The PHP:

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');
$val = 20;
echo "data: The value is: " . $val . "\n\n";
flush();
```

And the js:

```
    var source;
    $(document).ready(function () {
      source = new EventSource("/eventeg.php");
      source.onmessage = function (evnt) {
        document.getElementById("serverevent").innerHTML = evnt.data;
      };
    });
```

As soon as I change the PHP file the page reflected the push within 'serverevent'.

**However simply attempting to convert into Laravel:**

PHP:

in routes web.php

```
Route::any('event', 'Event_c@eventTest');
```

Then - (to create re-usable code I have a repo as shown by the namespace)

```
    <?php

namespace App\DD_laravelAp\Controllers;

class RootEvent_c extends RootController_c {

  protected function start($init = null) {

  }

  public function eventTest() {
    header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
    header('Cache-Control: no-cache');
    $val = 10;
    echo "data: The value is: " . $val . "\n\n";
    flush();
  }

}
```

And finally the class that Laravel should use:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\DD_laravelAp\Controllers\RootEvent_c;

class Event_c extends RootEvent_c {

}
```

With the js changed to reflect the Laravel url structure:

```
  source = new EventSource("/event");
  source.onmessage = function (evnt) {
    document.getElementById("serverevent").innerHTML = evnt.data;
  };
```

The error from the console however is:

```
Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at http://domain/event
```

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade to more recent version of Laravel to solve this issue.